# Inserting a new node into a doubly linked list after a given node

Tags: c, list

This function inserts a new node after a given node in a doubly linked list.

It works well unless the list is empty or when given node is NULL.

I have tried to solve this problem by inserting the new node as head, but it doesn't add the new node or does problems when adding a second node.

```
void insert(Polynomial** node, int new_data, int pow) {
Polynomial* new_node = ( Polynomial*)malloc(sizeof( Polynomial));
new_node->num = new_data;
new_node->pow = pow;

if ((*node) == NULL) {
    new_node->prev = NULL;
    (*node) = new_node;
    return;
}

new_node->next = (*node)->next;
(*node)->next = new_node;
new_node->prev = (*node);

if (new_node->next != NULL)
    new_node->next->prev = new_node; 
}
```

Struct:

```
typedef struct Polynomial {
int num;
int pow;
struct Polynomial* next;
struct Polynomial* prev;
}Polynomial;
```

Comment: `node = new_node` only changes the *local* variable `node`, so your function doesn't modify the value of of the node pointer passed to it.

Comment: Tried using a pointer-to-pointer now, head node works, but it doesn't work when adding a second node into the list.

Comment: Show the new code. "It doesn't work" is not a valid problem description.

Comment: Edited the question with the new code

Comment: I keep getting new_node->next was 0xCDCDCDCD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a new list, the first node's `next` pointer is unspecified. This could lead to undefined behaviour when inserting the second node, e.g. the `0xcdcdcdcd` value you saw. Set it to null before returning:

```
if ((*node) == NULL) {
    new_node->prev = new_node->next = NULL;
    (*node) = new_node;
    return;
}
```

Comment: Oh thank you. It works well and I understand my mistake now. :)

Comment: It is good practice for new (and not so new) C programmers to initialize ALL variables when declared to prevent just such surprises `:)`